# Filling in array in PHP with missing years in ascending order

Tags: php, arrays

Having the following array of arrays:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2012"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2013"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2015"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2008"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2009"
      [1]=>
      float(7)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2010"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2011"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    } // <---------------------------- HERE I MISS YEAR 2012
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2013"
      [1]=>
      float(19)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      [1]=>
      float(8)
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2015"
      [1]=>
      float(8)
    }
  }
}
```

The first array is correct as it has the order year ascending order, `2012`, `2013`, `2014` and `2015`.
The second array has the issue as you can see it misses the year `2012`.

I want to fill all the missing years in ascending order (and add a float `0`), in the example would be to push the value `2012` into the array (the second array), with a `float` value of `0`.

```
   array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2012"
      [1]=>
      float(0)
    }
```

So my desired output would be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2012"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2013"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2015"
      [1]=>
      float(1)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2008"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2009"
      [1]=>
      float(7)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2010"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2011"
      [1]=>
      float(2)
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2012"
      [1]=>
      float(0)
    }
    [5]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2013"
      [1]=>
      float(19)
    }
    [6]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2014"
      [1]=>
      float(8)
    }
    [7]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2015"
      [1]=>
      float(8)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is an 'easy' example as it only misses one year, but I would like to have a 'general' script that can fix it doing the same; filling the missed year in ascending order and putting the float to 0.

`2008`, `2009`, `2013`, `2014`, to fill `2008`, `2009`, `2010`,. `2011`, `2012`, `2013`, `2014`.

This is my try, being `arraySeries` the name of the array. I'm stucked on the part I've to make the changes.

```
foreach ($arraySeries as $value) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($value as $innerArray) {
        if ($i == 0) {
                $firstYear = $innerArray[0];
            }
        $year = $innerArray[0];
        if ($year == $firstYear) {
            echo "It's the same year, ok";
        } else {
            echo "Missing year! - Fill value";
            // Do stuff
        }
        var_dump($year);
        $i++;
        $firstYear++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
    $firstYear = null;
}
```

Any other more elegant / better performance solutions are welcome.

PS: I'm using PHP 5.2 (it's not my machine and I cant update the version)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to pop out of my mind is just to get the years provided from data (with the missing year).

Then, get the minimum and maximum of it, create a complete year range.

Compare the collected data so that you'll know the missing year. After that is straight forward, add the missing year, then the usual sorting:

```
foreach($array as &$first) {
    $years = array_map('reset', $first); // get all years first
    $min = min($years); // min and max
    $max = max($years);
    $year_range = range($min, $max); // create complete years
    $missing_years = array_diff($year_range, $years); // compare both all years to complete range to get the missing
    foreach($missing_years as $y) {
        $first[] = [$y, (float) 0]; // push missing year
    }
    // sort by date
    usort($first, function($a, $b){
        return $a[0] - $b[0];
    });
}
```

Note: If your PHP can't support anonymous functions, just create a simple function outside and use it in `usort`.